# Side panes on the left and right with CSS and HTML

Tags: css, html

I like to create a site, where it is possible to open one Sidepane from the Left or one frome the right. I am not good in JavaScript (and I don't like it either) so that I would prefer a solution with pure CSS and HTML.
I found a site that does kind of exactly what I want, but using JS:

http://www.huntand.co/

Do you know any nice solutions?

Comment: If you want to do this on click (and not on hover) I'm afraid there is no non-hackish solution without JS.

Comment: Sorry, but SO requires that you make an effort and bring more specific questions. We aren't a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not agree with your philosophy in regards to learning, you could accomplish a double pain solution using CSS.  Although don't expect to fire off any click events (you should really attempt to learn JS).  At least make an effort.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col left"></div>
  <div class="col right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:#F8F8F8;
  position:relative;
}
.col{
   height:100%;
   width:60%;
   min-width:40px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   transition: 1s ease;
}
.left{
   background:#888;
   left:-50%;
}
.right{
   background:#222;
   right:-50%;

}
.right:hover{
  right:0;
}
.left:hover{
  left:0;
}
```

Example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dclappert/pen/waKEaw)

Comment: OK thanks David. In the meantime I already accepted the necessity of JS. So I use js and even jquery in my current state. The structure is the same as yours but there has to be more "logic" behind, that css cannot implement.